# C++ Library Troubles with GCC

Tags: c++, sockets, gcc, codeblocks, undefined-reference

I'm brand new to C++ but I have a lot of general experience with programming, so I'm familiar with most low level concepts.

Anyway, I thought I'd try writing an IRC client, since IRC appears to have a relatively simple TCP protocol. (It's so easy, you can access and use a server via Telnet, it's unpractical, but doable)

So I googled "C++ socket library" and came across [dlib](http://dlib.net/), a general purpose library that includes some socket support.

I look into the documents, found an example that should echo anything it receives, and tried to compile it.
But, I got *tons* of errors about "undefined references" to functions.

I don't really know what to do now. 
Can anyone give me some advice ?

I'm building this in Code::Blocks v10.05 and GCC 4.4.1 
(I'd use 4.6.1, but I've yet to figure out how to get Code::Blocks to compile that way)

Here's the **exact** example:

```
// The contents of this file are in the public domain. See LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt
/*

    This is an example illustrating the use of the sockets and
    server components from the dlib C++ Library.

    This is a simple echo server.  It listens on port 1234 for incoming
    connections and just echos back any data it receives.

*/




#include "dlib/sockets.h"
#include "dlib/server.h"
#include "dlib/ref.h" // for ref()
#include <iostream>

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;



class serv : public server::kernel_1a_c
{

    void on_connect  (
        connection& con
    )
    {
        char ch;
        while (con.read(&ch,1) > 0)
        {
            // we are just reading one char at a time and writing it back
            // to the connection.  If there is some problem writing the char
            // then we quit the loop.
            if (con.write(&ch,1) != 1)
                break;
        }
    }

};


void thread(serv& our_server)
{
    try
    {
        // Start the server.  start() blocks until the server is shutdown
        // by a call to clear()
        our_server.start();
    }
    catch (socket_error& e)
    {
        cout << "Socket error while starting server: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "Error while starting server: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    try
    {
        serv our_server;

        // set up the server object we have made
        our_server.set_listening_port(1234);
        our_server.set_max_connections(1000);

        // create a thread that will start the server.   The ref() here allows us to pass
        // our_server into the threaded function by reference.
        thread_function t(thread, dlib::ref(our_server));

        cout << "Press enter to end this program" << endl;
        cin.get();
        // this will cause the server to shut down
        our_server.clear();
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Some error occurred" << endl;
    }
}
```

And then here is the output:

```
-------------- Build: Release in test ---------------

Compiling: main.cpp
Linking console executable: bin\test.exe
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `dlib::logger::~logger()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1d3): undefined reference to `dlib::logger::logger(char const*)'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3cf): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::threaded_object()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x44a): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::start()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4ef): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::wait() const'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x523): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::~threaded_object()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5e8): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::~threaded_object()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x701): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::~threaded_object()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4serv10on_connectERN4dlib10connectionE[serv::on_connect(dlib::connection&)]+0x20): undefined reference to `dlib::connection::read(char*, long)'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4serv10on_connectERN4dlib10connectionE[serv::on_connect(dlib::connection&)]+0x38): undefined reference to `dlib::connection::write(char const*, long)'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15thread_functionD0Ev[dlib::thread_function::~thread_function()]+0x43): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::wait() const'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15thread_functionD0Ev[dlib::thread_function::~thread_function()]+0x70): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::~threaded_object()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15thread_functionD0Ev[dlib::thread_function::~thread_function()]+0xbe): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::~threaded_object()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15thread_functionD1Ev[dlib::thread_function::~thread_function()]+0x43): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::wait() const'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15thread_functionD1Ev[dlib::thread_function::~thread_function()]+0x70): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::~threaded_object()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15thread_functionD1Ev[dlib::thread_function::~thread_function()]+0xb3): undefined reference to `dlib::threaded_object::~threaded_object()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5clearEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::clear()]+0x10e): undefined reference to `dlib::connection::shutdown()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE18service_connectionEPv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::service_connection(void*)]+0x9e): undefined reference to `dlib::close_gracefully(dlib::connection*, unsigned long)'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE18service_connectionEPv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::service_connection(void*)]+0x352): undefined reference to `dlib::logger::logger_stream::print_end_of_line()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE18service_connectionEPv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::service_connection(void*)]+0x3c5): undefined reference to `dlib::logger::logger_stream::print_header_and_stuff()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE18service_connectionEPv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::service_connection(void*)]+0x3f3): undefined reference to `dlib::logger::logger_stream::print_end_of_line()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0x58): undefined reference to `dlib::create_listener(dlib::listener*&, unsigned short, std::string const&)'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0x11d): undefined reference to `dlib::listener::accept(dlib::connection*&, unsigned long)'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0x244): undefined reference to `dlib::threads_kernel_shared::thread_pool()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0x25b): undefined reference to `dlib::threads_kernel_shared::threader::create_new_thread(void (*)(void*), void*)'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0x4a3): undefined reference to `dlib::listener::~listener()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0x648): undefined reference to `dlib::connection::~connection()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0x949): undefined reference to `dlib::listener::~listener()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0x9bd): undefined reference to `dlib::connection::~connection()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0xdd0): undefined reference to `dlib::listener::~listener()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0xdf4): undefined reference to `dlib::connection::~connection()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0xf7c): undefined reference to `dlib::listener::~listener()'
obj\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4dlib15server_kernel_1INS_12set_kernel_1IPNS_10connectionENS_27binary_search_tree_kernel_1IS3_cNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEESt4lessIS3_EEES6_EEE5startEv[dlib::server_kernel_1<dlib::set_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, dlib::binary_search_tree_kernel_1<dlib::connection*, char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, std::less<dlib::connection*> >, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >::start()]+0xfa0): undefined reference to `dlib::connection::~connection()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 5 seconds)
33 errors, 0 warnings
```

Comment: Did you put any files in your project? Or did you look at a tutorial and thought writing `#include` would suffice?

Comment: Looks like you're not linking to dlib?

Comment: anon, I've tried adding the source files folder both in GCC's include directory (switched the #includes to use <>s) and to the project directory. cdhowie, how do I do that ? Is it a compiler flag I need to use ?

Comment: If you're brand new to C++, look into the `boost` library's implementation of ASIO.  It's not the easiest library to use and the documentation is really just made of of doxygen comments from the code, but the examples are good.  Working with C++ now, `boost` is basically a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're missing the option that tells gcc to link with the dlib library. I don't know what the specific setting thing to do for Code::Blocks is but in general with gcc you would need to use the -l option like this:

`gcc <other compiler options> -ldlib`

#### update

Ok I had a better look into this and it looks like dlib doesn't actually build a library for you. The common way that external libraries packages work is by providing a makefile that build you the *.a or *.so files that you need to link with. However dlib doesn't provide this and requires you to add its special `source.cpp` to your build settings. Again I don't know how to do this in codeblocks but the following worked for me when compiling and linking that socket example:

`g++ -o dlib_socket -I ../dlib-17.42/ -lpthread -lX11 dlib_socket.cpp ../dlib-17.42/dlib/all/source.cpp`

In the example above I extracted dlib into the parent directory (hence the ../dlib-17.42/dlib)

Comment: Okay, I'll assume I'm going to need that as dll anyway (sorry, very new to C++). I tried compiling a source file which #includes everything else and it ran out of memory, even then, that would've produced an executable. What's the compiler flag for making a DLL?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read dlib's [How to compile](http://dlib.net/compile.html) page?  It sounds like you forgot to add dlib/all/source.cpp to your project.  Adding that should make those linker errors go away.  Also, since you are using Code::Blocks, you will need to tell it to link with these windows libraries: gdi32, comctl32, user32, ws2_32, and imm32.

It's also worth pointing out that there is a free version of [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) which you can use to compile these C++ programs.  If you are compiling on windows I would definitely recommend using this compiler instead of Code::Blocks.

On my system (Windows XP in a virtual box VM with 3.5GB of RAM) Code::Blocks compiles without issue using the above method.  However, if it refuses to compile dlib/all/source.cpp you should just add the files listed in dlib/all/source.cpp to your project individually instead.  The only reason source.cpp is included is for convenience and it really isn't needed.

Comment: Okay, just tried that, but I get `cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes` when I try to compile dlib/all/source.cpp. I used all the recommend flags as well.

Comment: That's no good.  How much RAM is in your system?  At any rate, I updated my answer with instructions that should let you compile.

Answer (score 0):

First and formost
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ tells you everything you need to know about socket programming.
Jumping into a libary before you understand the basics is counter productive with sockets.
Most socket libarys are simple wrapers which handle the data structs for you.

here is a class i wrote years ago for windows.

```
#pragma once
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
class cMySocket {
public:
    cMySocket(void);
    ~cMySocket(void);

    int startup_server(int type, unsigned __int16 port, const char* ip );
    void shutdown_server();
    operator SOCKET();
    cMySocket & operator=(const SOCKET &s);

    bool           running;
    SOCKET         m_socket;
    sockaddr_in    service;
    sockaddr_in    client_addr;
};
cMySocket::cMySocket(void){
    m_socket = SOCKET_ERROR;
    running = false;
}

cMySocket::~cMySocket(void){
    if( m_socket != SOCKET_ERROR )
        closesocket(m_socket);
}

int cMySocket::startup_server(int type, unsigned __int16 port, const char* ip ){
    unsigned long iMode = 1;

    m_socket = socket(AF_INET, type, 0);
    if (m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        throw "Error at socket()\n";
    }

    if( ioctlsocket(m_socket, FIONBIO, &iMode) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        closesocket(m_socket);
        throw "Error at ioctlsocket()\n";
    }

    memset( &service, 0, sizeof( service ));
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    service.sin_port = htons(port);

    if( bind(m_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR ){
        closesocket(m_socket);
        throw "Error at bind()\n";
    }
    iMode = 1;
    if ( ioctlsocket( m_socket, FIONBIO, &iMode ) )
    {
        closesocket(m_socket);
        throw "Error at iostlcosket()\n";
    }
    if( type == SOCK_STREAM ){
        if( listen( m_socket, 10) == SOCKET_ERROR ){
            closesocket(m_socket);
            throw "Error at listen()\n";
        }
    }
    running = true;
    return 1;
}

void cMySocket::shutdown_server(){
    closesocket( m_socket );
    m_socket = SOCKET_ERROR;
    running = false;
}

cMySocket::operator SOCKET () { 
    return m_socket; 
}

cMySocket & cMySocket::operator=(const SOCKET &s){  
    m_socket = s;
    return *this;
}
```

You still have to use connect, accept, send, recv functions on your on, as well as error checking.
Unless your using some kind of implimted protocal provided by your libary, I suggest coding the socket implimentation yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You would be better off not using C::B. Try NetBeans because it will produce make files.

Right click on the project and go to build options. There you will find linker. Add the library from there.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/